# SQL Transact, Dynamic SQL, conditional pivot

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, case

I am trying convert a vertical data set to a horizontal data set. The current data set lists a unique id(VARCHAR) that may appear up to (13) times in the data set. Each id row contains (1) c_id value, (1) op value, (1) score value, (1) sp_id value plus additional values unique to that c_id as well as some common such as p. Only two values cannot be null id and c_id. The op value can be summed across id rows to 100 and is an edit check on the accuracy of the data.

```
   DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
        (
          id VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
         ,c_id INT NOT NULL
         ,op FLOAT NULL
         ,score FLOAT NULL
         ,sp_id INT NULL     
         ,p VARCHAR(2) NULL
        ) 
        INSERT INTO @Table1 
        (id, c_id, op, score, sp_id, p)
    VALUES ('1', '1', '51', '4','2','a')
          ,('1', '2', NULL, '3','1',NULL)
          ,('1', '3','20', '4',NULL,'a')
          ,('1', '4', '20', '4','5','a')
          ,('1', '5', '9', '4','4','a')
          ,('2', '6','100', NULL, NULL,NULL)
          ,('3', '7','100','4',NULL,'a')
          ;
```

The data looks like this

| id | c_Id | op | score | sp_id | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 51 | 4 | 2 | a |
| 1 | 2 |  | 3 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | 20 | 4 |  | a |
| 1 | 4 | 20 | 4 | 5 | a |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 4 | a |
| 2 | 6 | 100 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 7 | 100 | 4 | NULL | a |

The sample data I'm providing has 7 rows, I want to convert it to (3) rows, one for each unique id. The row 1 output will have (4) c_id values, even though the original data set has (5) c_id values. When op is null or = 0, we do not create a new columns for that c_id, we do however capture score. If sp_id value is NULL, then cpid_score will also be NULL.

```
            DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
        (  p VARCHAR (2) NULL
          ,sum_op INT NULL
          ,id VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL         
          ,cid1 INT NULL
          ,op1 FLOAT NULL
          ,cid1_score FLOAT NULL
          ,spid1 INT NULL
          ,spid1_score FLOAT NULL       
          ,cid2 INT NULL
          ,op2 FLOAT NULL
          ,cid2_score FLOAT NULL
          ,spid2 INT NULL   
          ,spid2_score FLOAT NULL     
          ,cid3 INT NULL
          ,op3 FLOAT NULL
          ,cid3_score FLOAT NULL
          ,spid3 INT NULL   
          ,spid3_score FLOAT NULL     
          ,cid4 INT NULL
          ,op4 FLOAT NULL
          ,cid4_score FLOAT NULL
          ,spid4 INT NULL
          ,spid4_score FLOAT NULL
        ) 
    
    INSERT INTO @Table2
        (  p,sum_op ,id,cid1,op1,cid1_score,spid1,spid1_score,cid2,op2,cid2_score,spid2,spid2_score,cid3,op3,cId3_score,spid3,spid3_score,cid4,op4,cid4_score,spid4,spid4_score)
    VALUES ('a','100','1','1','51','4','2','3','3','20','4',NULL,NULL,'4','20','4','5',NULL,'5','9','4','4',NULL),
           (NULL,'100','2','6',NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
           ('a','100','3','7','4', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL)
          ;
```

Switched to dynamic sql since I do not know how many cid will be associated with each id over time. Not sure how to iterate with _ 1 , _ 2.... values

```
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
    -- Generate the dynamic column list based on cid values, how do I add  underscore and iterative #
    SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ', '') + CAST(cid AS VARCHAR)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT cid
      FROM table1
    ) AS Contacts;
    
    -- Build the dynamic SQL statement
    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT id, ' + @columns + ', op, score, spid
    FROM (
      SELECT id, 
             CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY contact_id) AS VARCHAR) AS cid_column,
             cid, op, score, spid
      FROM table1
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
      MAX(cid)
      FOR cid IN (' + @columns + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY id;
    ';
    
    -- Execute the dynamic SQL statement
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated with existing code, tried some pivots as well

Comment: In INSERT INTO @Table1  (id, c_Id, op, score, sp_Id, ``st``) It is implied ``p``?

Comment: updated yes st should have been p

Comment: You show 4 groups of column, not 5. Conditions not clear for that - skip row with c_id=2.

Comment: becuase c_Id = 2 where op = O or NULL, they are not assigend a row in output, we account for that c_id score with c_id1 row

Comment: Column type ``sp_Id VARCHAR (3) NULL``  and  sum as '1'+'2'='3'. Is there sp_id contains only numeric simbols?

Comment: Are you on a platform that has `first_value()` with an `ignore nulls` option?

Comment: I don't understand what you're describing as "conditions". `partition by id order by id` makes no sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear.
First, try convert with conditions your data to

```
with t0 as(
  select id,c_id,op,score,sp_id,p
     ,case when coalesce(op,0)<>0 then c_id
      else
         max(c_id)over(partition by id order by c_id 
             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
      end c_id_gr
  from test
)
,t1 as(
  select id,min(c_id)c_id,sum(op)op,max(score)op_score,sum(sp_id)sp_id,sum(sp_id)spid_score,max(p)p
  from t0
  group by id,c_id_gr
)
```

query result as source for next queries

| id | c_id | op | op_score | sp_id | spid_score | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 51 | 4 | 3 | 3 | a |
| 1 | 3 | 20 | 4 | null | null | a |
| 1 | 4 | 20 | 4 | 5 | 5 | a |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 4 | 4 | a |
| 2 | 6 | 100 | null | null | null | null |
| 3 | 7 | 100 | 4 | null | null | a |

and then pivot to desired form:

```
,upvt as(
SELECT ID, rn, concat(h,rn) h, v 
FROM   
   (SELECT ID,p
      ,row_number()over(partition by id order by c_id)rn
      ,sum(op)over(partition by id )sumop
      , c_id,op,op_score,sp_id,spid_score
   FROM t1) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (v  FOR h IN   
      (c_id,op,op_score,sp_id,spid_score)  
)AS unpvt
)
,pvt as(SELECT Id,c_id1,op1,op_score1,sp_id1,spid_score1
                 ,c_id2,op2,op_score2,sp_id2,spid_score2 
                 ,c_id3,op3,op_score3,sp_id3,spid_score3
                 ,c_id4,op4,op_score4,sp_id4,spid_score4
                 ,c_id5,op5,op_score5,sp_id5,spid_score5
FROM  (select id,h,v from upvt)upvt
PIVOT  
(  
  AVG(v)  
  FOR h IN (c_id1,op1,op_score1,sp_id1,spid_score1
           ,c_id2,op2,op_score2,sp_id2,spid_score2 
           ,c_id3,op3,op_score3,sp_id3,spid_score3
           ,c_id4,op4,op_score4,sp_id4,spid_score4
           ,c_id5,op5,op_score5,sp_id5,spid_score5
           )  
) AS PivotTable
)
select * from t1 order by id,c_id;
select * 
from (select id,sum(op) sum_op,max(p)p from test group by id) hdr
left join pvt on pvt.id=hdr.id
```

Result see in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V04YUqb2)

It is quite possible to make a request dynamic. The basic idea persists: unpivot then pivot.

The presentation option you have chosen in the form of a long table does not seem very convenient to me, especially if there are 17 such groups. However, it's your choice.

Comment: rewrote the question to trty and make it more clear